# CSS word-break property in hover effect

Tags: html, css

I want to create a cell that has `text-overflow: ellipsis` for `max-width: 250px;` Now I want that when I hover on it, the line(paragraph/text) will break and become multiline and overflow become normal. I use `word-break: break-all` for it.

my code:

```html
<div class="mytableoverflow">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus ut massa non iaculis. Donec aliquet viverra arcu, et tempus magna efficitur a. Sed condimentum, magna a finibus fermentum.
</div>

<style>
.mytableoverflow{
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .mytableoverflow:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    max-width: 250px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
</style>
```

But unfortunately, the targeted hover effect can't be archived. How can I fix it?

Comment: change `word-break: break-all;` to `white-space: normal;` ?

Answer (score 1):

This Should Do The Work

```css
.mytableoverflow {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.mytableoverflow:hover {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytableoverflow">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus ut massa non iaculis. Donec aliquet viverra arcu, et tempus magna efficitur a. Sed condimentum, magna a finibus fermentum.
</div>
```

You were doing everything correct but you were not changing the `white-space` property in `:hover` to `normal`